# Remove postgresql Error

Tags: 14.04, postgresql

I'm trying to remove PostgreSQL 9.1 from ubuntu 14.04 but I'm getting an error :

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql
...
Package 'postgresql' is not installed, so not removed
update-alternatives: error: alternative pg_basebackup.1.gz can't be slave of postmaster.1.gz : it is a slave of psql.1.gz
dpkg: error processing postgresql-client-9.3 (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
```

I've tried this solution :

```
update-alternatives --remove pg_basebackup.l.gz /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/man/man1/pg_basebackup.1.gz
```

But it didn't work.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that the `postgresql` package name isn't exactly `postgresql`

The following command will catch more patterns of `postgresql`:

```
apt-get --purge remove postgresql\*
```

---

Note: You should make sure that PostgreSQL isn't running.

The following command should return nothing:

```
ps -C postgres
```